# Why won't changes reflect in my Xamarin.Forms project or SQLite database

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm

**UPDATE - Issue #1 is Solved, Issue#2 is still unsolved**
You can view a very crude demonstration video of my issue at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5_6KJ0QJouM

I am building have a **Xamarin.Forms** app with an **SQLite** database using the **MVVM** design pattern and **C#**

When try to Save a record to the database from a `View` the update/save does not appear to be saving to the SQLite database or reflect in other `Views`.

I know the database `Save` method does work as I have created some dummy data when the application first loads (in `App.xaml.cs`) using the `DeveloperData.cs` file.

I have two issues.

**(SOLVED) Issue 1 - Data not Saving to Database**
when I call the `Save` command from the `MerchandiserEditPage.xaml`, which uses the  `MerchandiserEditPageViewModel.cs` ViewModel, the record does not appear to save.

**Issue 2 - Changes Reflecting in other Views**
Once the updated data is saved to the database, how can I reflect that change in other views?  After I Save a record from the `MerchandiserEditPage` that `View` is "Popped" off the stack and the user is returned to the `MerchandiserProfileView`.  I want the updated data to be reflected in all other views on the stack.  But this doesn't appear to be happening? (I tested this using hardcoded data and the same issue occurred, so problem is not directly related to issue 1)

There are many files in my project, that can be viewed/downloaded from my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/minlopalis/XamarinFormsMobileAppProject.git) but I will concentrate on the following in this question.

- MerchandiserEditPage.xaml (View)
- MerchandiserProfilePage.xaml (View)
- MerchandiserDatabase.cs (Database Functions)x
- MerchandiserEditPageViewModel.cs x

View my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/minlopalis/XamarinFormsMobileAppProject.git) for the full project.

**MerchandiserDatabase.cs** (Database Functions)

```
using SQLite;

namespace MobileApp.Database
{
    public class MerchandiserDatabase
    {
        private static SQLiteConnection database = DependencyService.Get<IDatabaseConnection>().DbConnection(); 
        private readonly static object collisionLock = new object();

        public MerchandiserDatabase()
        {
            database.CreateTable<Models.Merchandiser>();
        }


        public static void SaveMerchandiser(Models.Merchandiser merchandiser)
        {
            lock (collisionLock)
            {
                if (merchandiser.Id != 0)
                {
                    database.Update(merchandiser);
                }
                else
                {
                    database.Insert(merchandiser);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**MerchandiserEditPageViewModel.cs** (ViewModel) **UPDATED**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MobileApp.ViewModels
{
    public class MerchandiserEditPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
    { 
        public string PageTitle { get; } = "Edit Merchandiser Profile";

        public Command SaveCommand { get; set; }

        private string name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private string phone;
        public string Phone
        {
            get { return phone; }
            set
            {
                phone = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private string email;
        public string Email
        {
            get { return email; }
            set
            {
                email = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public MerchandiserEditPageViewModel(Models.Merchandiser selectedMerchandiser)
        {
            Name = selectedMerchandiser.Name;
            Phone = selectedMerchandiser.Phone;
            Email = selectedMerchandiser.Email;

            SaveCommand = new Command( async ()=> {

                selectedMerchandiser.Name = this.Name;
                selectedMerchandiser.Phone = this.Phone;
                selectedMerchandiser.Email = this.Email;

                Database.MerchandiserDatabase.SaveMerchandiser(selectedMerchandiser);
                await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopModalAsync();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**MerchandiserEditPage.xaml** (View)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MobileApp.Views.MerchandiserEditPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>

            <!--Page Heading-->
            <StackLayout Spacing="0">
                <Label Text="{Binding PageTitle}"
                       Style="{StaticResource PageTitle}"/>
                <BoxView HeightRequest="1" Color="LightGray" />
            </StackLayout>

            <!-- Merchandiser Profile -->
            <StackLayout Margin="10">

                <Label Text="Name"/>
                <Entry Text="{Binding Name}"/>

                <Label Text="Phone"/>
                <Entry Text="{Binding Phone}"/>

                <Label Text="Email"/>
                <Entry Text="{Binding Email}"/>

                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                             HorizontalOptions="Center">
                    <Button Text="Cancel"
                            Clicked="CancelButton_Clicked"/>
                    <Button Text="Save"
                            Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"/>
                </StackLayout>
                
            </StackLayout>

        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**MerchandiserEditPage.xaml.cs** (View - Code Behind)

```
public partial class MerchandiserEditPage : ContentPage
    {
        Models.Merchandiser SelectedMerchandiser { get; set; }

        public MerchandiserEditPage (Models.Merchandiser selectedMerchandiser)
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            SelectedMerchandiser = selectedMerchandiser;
            this.BindingContext = new ViewModels.MerchandiserEditPageViewModel(selectedMerchandiser);
        }

        async private void CancelButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
        }

    }
```

**MerchandiserProfilePage.xaml** (View - XAML)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MobileApp.Views.MerchandiserProfilePage"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>

            <!--Page Heading-->
            <StackLayout Spacing="0">
                <Label Text="{Binding PageTitle}"
                       Style="{StaticResource PageTitle}"/>
                <BoxView HeightRequest="1" Color="LightGray" />
            </StackLayout>
            
            <!-- Merchandiser Profile -->
            <StackLayout Margin="10">
                
                <Label Text="Name"/>
                <Entry Text="{Binding Name}"
                       IsEnabled="False"/>

                <Label Text="Phone"/>
                <Entry Text="{Binding Phone}"
                   IsEnabled="False"/>

                <Label Text="Email"/>
                <Entry Text="{Binding Email}"
                   IsEnabled="False"/>

                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                             HorizontalOptions="Center">
                    <Button Text="Back"
                            Clicked="BackButton_Clicked"/>
                    <Button Text="Edit"
                            Clicked="EditButton_Clicked"/>
                </StackLayout>

                <Button Text="Delete"
                        Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}"/>

            </StackLayout>

        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**MerchandiserProfilePage.xaml.cs** - (View - Code Behind)

```
    public partial class MerchandiserProfilePage : ContentPage
    {
        private Models.Merchandiser SelectedMerchandister { get; set; }

        public MerchandiserProfilePage (Models.Merchandiser selectedMerchandiser)
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            SelectedMerchandister = selectedMerchandiser;
            this.BindingContext = new ViewModels.MerchandiserProfilePageViewModel(selectedMerchandiser);
        }

        async private void BackButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
        }

        async private void EditButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Views.MerchandiserEditPage(SelectedMerchandister));
        }
    }
```

**MerchandiserProfilePageViewModel.cs** (ViewModel)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MobileApp.ViewModels
{
    public class MerchandiserProfilePageViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public string PageTitle { get; } = "Merchandiser Profile";

        public Command DeleteCommand { get; }

        private string name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name;  }
            set
            {
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private string phone;
        public string Phone
        {
            get { return phone; }
            set
            {
                phone = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private string email;
        public string Email
        {
            get { return email; }
            set
            {
                email = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        
        public MerchandiserProfilePageViewModel(Models.Merchandiser selectedMerchandiser)
        {
            Name = selectedMerchandiser.Name;
            Phone = selectedMerchandiser.Phone;
            Email = selectedMerchandiser.Email;
            DeleteCommand = new Command( async()=> {

                bool deleteConfirmed = await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Confirm Delete",$"Are you sure you want to delete {selectedMerchandiser.Name} as a Merchandiser?","Yes","No");

                if (deleteConfirmed)
                {
                    // TODO: Delete Merchandiser
                    await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopModalAsync();
                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your VM creates a **new** copy of the object that you are editing, so any changes made to it are not reflected it the other views that are bound to the original copy of the object.  You can either change this, or use some mechanism like an event or MessagingCenter to notify them that they need to refresh their copy of the data

Comment: I have tried passing in the `selectedMerchandiser` from  the `MerchandiserEditPageViewModel` to the `Save Command` and this did not work.  So I created a `new` instance of the `Merchandiser`for testing in the hope this would add another record (but I forgot to revert back to original code before posting).  Is this what you are mentioning?  I don't want to learn something new such as MessagingCenter as this is for a school project due tomorrow and I don't have the time to learn something new.    Can you please provide some code to show me what changes I need to make?

Comment: the code in your repo crashes on startup for me so I can't tell you what you need to change

Comment: I updated my code to reflect the changes. My code seems to execute for me.  Did you add SQLite?  I'm using VS2017 and Android Nexus 5 Oreo 8.1 API 27 as my emulator.  My Target Framework is .NET2.0.  To be honest, I have had nothing but problems with Xamarin.Forms and using my code on other devices.  This issue doesn't seem to be isolated to me either.  Many other students are facing the same problem

Comment: Also, you're setting the private variable and not the public one `this.email = selectedMerchandiser.Email;` instead of `Email = selectedMerchandiser.Email;` so `OnPropertyChanged()` isn't firing to notify the UI of any changes

Comment: Xamarin is a great platform, but Mobile is complicated, and cross-platform even more so.  I'm not sure I would recommend it for students who did not have a deep C# background already

Comment: also, updating a SQLite record won't magically cause your UI to update, so if that is your expectation it will never work

Comment: I wasn't expecting SQLite to reflect the changes without some help, but a problem not really discussed yet and as indicated in Issue#1, is that my data doesn't seem to be saving to the Database?  I know my Database Save method works as I have successfully used it for creating dummy data, but when using it from `MerchandiserEditPageViewModel.cs` is does not seem to work.

Comment: "does not seem to work" is not very descriptive.  What specifically are you doing to validate the save?  If you save a record and then query the db again do you see the record?

Comment: My application is using data already saved in an SQLite database which I initially created at runtime using the same Save method in the Database file.  The "Dummy Data" is showing in my list views so I know the records are saved to the database.  However when I run the same Save method the changes don't seem to be reflected in the database? I test this by re-running my application to see if the changes are reflected.

I am happy to provide a live demonstration if that will help? (I need to find an app that will let me do that first) I can show my app running and the problem I'm facing?

Comment: I run your code and get two Buttons - Supervisor causes a crash, the other leads to a Login page that has a cancel button and no other UI

Comment: your methods that create the test data erase all existing data first, so any previous mods you made would be deleted and replaced with the same test data

Comment: I only ran the test data once and then commented it out, it's stored in the `App.xaml.cs` file... I have created a very rough video using my phone to show the issue im facing and show what files i'm referring to.  view it at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GCtGWMe7msc

Comment: put a breakpoint in the save code and step through it to verify that its executing as expected.   After the save add a query to load the same record to verify it.

Comment: I found one major problem with my code, and that is the `MerchandiserPageViewModel` was binding to a List and not the database, I have corrected the problem so this has solved Issue #1.    I'm still stuck on issue #2.   See new video here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=miYxKM3d10Y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a hardcoded set of data in your VM instead of loading it from the db

```
public MerchandisersPageViewModel()
{
    //Merchandisers = new ObservableCollection<Models.Merchandiser>(Database.MerchandiserDatabase.GetMerchandisers());
    Merchandisers = new ObservableCollection<Models.Merchandiser>()
    {
       new Models.Merchandiser { Id=1, Name="Barney Rubble", Phone="021 321 654", Email="barney@rubble.com"},
       new Models.Merchandiser { Id=2, Name="Frank Grimes", Phone="022 456 789", Email="grimey@homersfriend.com"},
       new Models.Merchandiser { Id=3, Name="Perry Platypus", Phone="023 789 456", Email="perry@agentp.com"},
    };
}
```

Update:

in `MerchandiserProfilePageViewModel`, get rid of the properties for `Name`, `Phone` and `EMail`

then in `MerchandiserProfilePage.xaml` change the bindings

```
<Entry Text="{Binding SelectedMerchandiser.Name}" IsEnabled="False"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Jason, we both found that issue together.  :) Issue #1 is solved.
I have created a new video outlining the remaining problem https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=miYxKM3d10Y

Comment: Updated Video outlining the Issue #2 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5_6KJ0QJouM

Comment: each VM has it's own properties for Name/Phone/Email, and changes to those properties on one VM do not affect the other VM.  Instead each VM should just have a Merchandiser property that all reference the same object, so changes to one will impact the other.  And the Merchandiser model should implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Jason, I can't thank you enough for your help, things are slowly starting to make sense,  I am so close to solving this issue.  

I have updated the Merchandiser model, and other bits of code and part of my app is working as expected, but other parts aren't.  . see update video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vfO9zvOjizU

Essentially the `EditPage` and `ProfilePage` don't seem to be syncing but the `ListView` is updating! 

I have updated my code in StackOverflow https://github.com/minlopalis/XamarinFormsMobileAppProject.git

Comment: see my expanded example

Comment: Thank you Jason, your efforts on this are highly appreciated. I finally have it working as expected.